# Azure Cosmos BulkExecuter Method not found

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am using **Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDb** v2.1.3 and **Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDb.BulkExecuter** v1.4.0 and when I run the code:

```
public async Task CreateMultipleAsync(IEnumerable<JObject> models)
{
    var collectionLink = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_databaseName, _collectionName);
    var collection = await _client.ReadDocumentCollectionAsync(collectionLink);
    var bulkExecutor = new BulkExecutor(_client, collection);

    try
    {
        await bulkExecutor.InitializeAsync();
        var response = await bulkExecutor.BulkImportAsync(models, true);
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

I get this error:

> Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1 Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Routing.PartitionKeyRangeCache.TryLookupAsync(System.String, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Routing.CollectionRoutingMap, System.Threading.CancellationToken, Boolean)'.

I have seen a few people with this issue (It seems to keep popping up) and they suggest using v2.1.3 and v1.4.0 respectively, which I am already doing.

I am using **.net 4.6.2**. Does anyone know why this is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@r3plica ,

This was the old issue which has been fixed with 1.1.2 release or higher of the BulkExecutor.

I tried to reproduce your issue using [Github Repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-bulkexecutor-dotnet-getting-started) to run BulkImportAsync method of BulkExecutor, worked perfectly fine for me.

I used below method to CreatePartitionCollection-

```
static internal async Task<DocumentCollection> CreatePartitionedCollectionAsync(DocumentClient client, string databaseName,
            string collectionName, int collectionThroughput)
        {
            PartitionKeyDefinition partitionKey = new PartitionKeyDefinition
            {
                Paths = new Collection<string> { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CollectionPartitionKey"] }
            };
            DocumentCollection collection = new DocumentCollection { Id = collectionName, PartitionKey = partitionKey };

            try
            {
                collection = await client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(
                    UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(databaseName),
                    collection,
                    new RequestOptions { OfferThroughput = collectionThroughput });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }

            return collection;
        }
```

And then in Main method used BulkImport like below:-

// Prepare for bulk import.

// Creating documents with simple partition key here.
        string partitionKeyProperty = dataCollection.PartitionKey.Paths[0].Replace("/", "");

```
    long numberOfDocumentsToGenerate = long.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NumberOfDocumentsToImport"]);
    int numberOfBatches = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NumberOfBatches"]);
    long numberOfDocumentsPerBatch = (long)Math.Floor(((double)numberOfDocumentsToGenerate) / numberOfBatches);

    // Set retry options high for initialization (default values).
    client.ConnectionPolicy.RetryOptions.MaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds = 30;
    client.ConnectionPolicy.RetryOptions.MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests = 9;

    IBulkExecutor bulkExecutor = new BulkExecutor(client, dataCollection);
    await bulkExecutor.InitializeAsync();

    // Set retries to 0 to pass control to bulk executor.
    client.ConnectionPolicy.RetryOptions.MaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds = 0;
    client.ConnectionPolicy.RetryOptions.MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests = 0;

    BulkImportResponse bulkImportResponse = null;
    long totalNumberOfDocumentsInserted = 0;
    double totalRequestUnitsConsumed = 0;
    double totalTimeTakenSec = 0;

    var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = tokenSource.Token;
```

var tasks = new List();

```
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation(String.Format("Executing bulk import for batch {0}", i));
            do
            {
                try
                {
                    bulkImportResponse = await bulkExecutor.BulkImportAsync(
                        documents: documentsToImportInBatch,
                        enableUpsert: true,
                        disableAutomaticIdGeneration: true,
                        maxConcurrencyPerPartitionKeyRange: null,
                        maxInMemorySortingBatchSize: null,
                        cancellationToken: token);
                }
                catch (DocumentClientException de)
                {
                    Trace.TraceError("Document client exception: {0}", de);
                    break;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Trace.TraceError("Exception: {0}", e);
                    break;
                }
            } while (bulkImportResponse.NumberOfDocumentsImported < documentsToImportInBatch.Count);



            totalNumberOfDocumentsInserted += bulkImportResponse.NumberOfDocumentsImported;
            totalRequestUnitsConsumed += bulkImportResponse.TotalRequestUnitsConsumed;
            totalTimeTakenSec += bulkImportResponse.TotalTimeTaken.TotalSeconds;
        },
        token));
```

Let me know if you need more details.